# Galaxy s3 - different version, one works fine, the other device not supported

Tags: android, google-play

My app is uploaded on google play, all is fine, but I have one problem with Galaxy S3 (different versions)

How is that possible that Samsung GT-i9305 & GT-i9308 (both are Samsung Galaxy S3) are not supported but GT-I93000 works fine?

Google console exclude it without a reason, how to fix that?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/iconnew"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Cardio"
        android:label="CardioMedic"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Cardio2"
        android:label="CardioMedic"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Wynik_cardio"
        android:label="CardioMedic"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Lipido"
        android:label="LipidoMedic"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Wynik_lipido"
        android:label="LipidoMedic"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Hipermedic"
        android:label="Hipermedic"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Wynik_hipermedic"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Pulmo"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Wynik_pulmo"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Rejestracja"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: post your manifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution but it's really weird!

minSdkVersion was 17 (Android 4.2)

I've changed this to 16 (Android 4.1) and now it looks fine, but I don't understand why all GT-i9305 were excluded, even if Galaxy has Android 4.4.4?

```
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "..."
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 4
    versionName "1.03"
}
```